# Using k-means clustering to train radial basis neural network for highly imbalanced dataset

Tags: neural-networks, clustering, python, k-means, radial-basis

I am trying to find prototype neurons for my radial basis neural network. My dataset has 30 attributes (of which 28 of them are the result of a single PCA) and 300.000 observations. It is a binary classification problem. After splitting my dataset into train and test set, I further split my train set into class1 and class0 observations. Then, I am using k-means clustering to find the position of centroids. To check the optimal cluster number I am using a silhouette score (I choose the number of clusters at which silhouette score is maximum). The code I use to find the clusters is:

```
kmeans_class1= KMeans(n_clusters=number_cluster_where_silhouette_score_is_max_for_class0, random_state=0).fit(X_class1)
class1_centers=kmeans_class1.cluster_centers_
kmeans_class0= KMeans(n_clusters=number_cluster_where_silhouette_score_is_max_for_class1, random_state=0).fit(X_class0)
class0_centers=kmeans_class0.cluster_centers_
centers=np.concatenate((class1_centers,class0_centers),axis=0)
```

However, I am not sure if k-means clustering is the correct method to adopt in my problem as my dataset is highly imbalanced and some observations from different classes are very similar to each other (also my results are not really pleasant)

What other methods could be appropriate for finding clusters using such a dataset? what can be suggested? I read that decision tree or orthogonal least square can also be applied to train radial basis neural networks.

Thank you.

Comment: You are stacking too many different techniques, the result becomes quite unpredictable. Something in this stack *is* going to fail all the time. Keep things simple! For example PCA *may* be a bad choice, because it reduces the influence of the direction of maximum variance and emphasizes orthogonal directions of lower variance. Why split the data and not use both classes (which means you get redundant centers)? Why "optimize" with Silhouette that does not relate to your actual objective - just choose k as deemed appropriate for the task?

Comment: The creators of dataset applied PCA, unfortunately, there is nothing I can do about it. I found clusters for each class. Why is not Silhouette score is relevant in such a scenario?

Comment: You are optimizing parameters and all that later anyway, so a rough estimate is enough. I'd assume more clusters will give better results even with worse silhouette.